# Creating Arrows Easily for Images

Tags: gimp, image-editing, vector-graphics, paint.net

I'm looking for a plugin or something along those lines for creating arrows for an image I'm working on. Basically it's just a screenshot of some software, but I want to annotate it and have arrows on it pointing to the various components.

It should look something like the below, or even something simpler.

[image]

The problem is that there doesn't seem to be an easy, free way of creating good arrows for any of the screenshots, short of importing actual images of arrows!

I prefer to use:

- [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)
- [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/)
- Other free software (beer or freedom, whichever)

What are my alternatives? I really want to stay away from Photoshop on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aviary's Falcon is an awesome image markup cloud app.  Easy to use, has arrows (and circles and such) and you don't have to download/install anything

[Falcon](http://aviary.com/launch/falcon)

Comment: Yeah, those arrows are exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: circles and arrows? awesome! does it put a paragraph on the back of each one too?

Comment: Looks like this solution died.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find anything free for this purpose, so I bought [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/).  It works extremely well for doing exactly what you are working on.  It's worth every penny I spent on it and would recommend it a million times over.

Comment: It does arrows?

Answer (score 0):

The absolute best I have found is the free (donation supported) [ScreenshotCaptor](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/).

It draws arrows and lets you rearrange them easily, change colors, line thickness, automatically add text captions, and it lets you come back and manipulate the objects at a later date.

Just fantastic life-saving software.

Answer (score 0):

Stick with GIMP, and the power of FREE* as in beer! Here's an [excellent article](http://ewaldertl.blogspot.ca/2013/05/marking-screenshot-with-circles-and.html) (also in [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20140114181408/http://ewaldertl.blogspot.ca/2013/05/marking-screenshot-with-circles-and.html), just in case) detailing how to do circles and arrows!

*some assembly required

Some key points:

- Make an ellipses selection; then, Edit -> Stroke Selection
- Install the scripts [found here](http://www.gimphelp.org/script28.shtml), for arrows based on the vector created using a GIMP path and a whole bunch of other goodies.

Comment: Just providing a link as an answer is discouraged. The link may become stale. Can you provide some basic info in the post?

Comment: It's been edited... I'm not going to go around making archives of everything, though.

Comment: Ah, the irony of the Gimp garnering downvotes and the online-only accepted answer dying. Quick explanation [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1491450&p=9349219#post9349219) -- `1. Draw a triangle using the [ Stars and Polygon Tool] Change the corners settings to 3 for a triangle. 2. Draw the tail using the [Rectangle tool]`. Profit.